# Strange translation behavior

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

working with Microsoft Bot Framework I've enabled the translation option getting and odd behavior.

Translation works if I reply with just one message else only last one will be translated. Here an italian native language chat, asking to speak english answering to question: *Who are you?*

[image]

My code looks like that:

```
string[] messageLines;
...
foreach (var line in messageLines)
{
    var msg = context.MakeMessage();                   
    msg.Text = line;
    msg.Type = "Message";   
    await context.PostAsync(msg);                    
}
```

Finally, I understand could happen with Skype and Facebook channels but it seems, for new users, the language setting is kept also for webchat, it means that if a webchat user select french and another user using another device opens a webchat french setting is still set... why ?!?!? 
Webchat user is always new, not like others and make no sense to keep language setting for this channel.
I believe is a platform issue but, is there something I wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: I had the same behavior, it seems that only direct responses are translated and not async responses.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying what language your bot's response is written in.

add line:

```
msg.Language = "it";
```

Comment: of course it was the first thing I tried...
Doesn't works and more if I do it do not translate neither last one

Answer (score 0):

you can implement `System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")`for Bot SDK v4.